# Launch the sqldeveloper.exe

Tags: java, sql, oracle, windows-10

When I launch the sqldeveloper application on windows 10 by double clicking on this software it shows the message **[unable to launch java virtual machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VDPA.png)**.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to install java in your machine as sqldeveloper needs jvm to start.